# Is the answer to $\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{(x^2+4)}{x} dx$ 0?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

My teacher is saying that the answer is 0, but some other sources online says the answer is "divergent". Which is it, and why is it the answer?

Comment: Look up BlackPenRedPen’s video of “the debate” over the integral from -1 to 1 of $1/x$. It comes down to considering properties of odd functions and Cauchy principal value.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=8ab70731b1553f17c11a3bbc87e0b605

Comment: The integrand does not integrate at 0.  It would be zero if you use a criterion like Cauchy Principal Value.

Answer (score 1):

This integral diverges ("does not exist" or "undefined" might be more appropriate). What is true however, is that 
$$
\int_{-2}^{-\epsilon} \frac{x^2+4}{x}dx+\int_\epsilon^{2} \frac{x^2+4}{x}dx=0
$$
for any $0<\epsilon\leq 2$.

Comment: Apologies, I'm a bit confused, are you saying that the answer to the question in the title is, or is not 0?

Comment: Did you mean $\Large\int_{-2}^{\color{red}-\epsilon}...$?

Comment: Absolutely. Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

There's a few interpretations. The most straightforward is to resort back to the definition of Riemann integrability (see Abbott, or any introductory real analysis textbook), in which we require $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ to be *bounded*. With this criterion, we immediately see that $f$ cannot be (Riemann) integrable (where $f(x)=(x^2+4)/x$), since $f$ has a pole at $0$. Hence, via this definition of integrability, the integral "diverges", or more properly, just does not exist in the first place, as $f$ does not satisfy the requirements of the definition of integrability.

However, as Adam mentions, for any $\varepsilon$ such that $0<\varepsilon\leq2$, we have that the following holds:
$$\int_{-2}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{x^2+4}{x}dx+\int_\varepsilon^2\frac{x^2+4}{x}dx=0$$
Hence, the following limit holds as well:
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_{-2}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{x^2+4}{x}dx+\int_\varepsilon^2\frac{x^2+4}{x}dx=0$$
This follows from considering the symmetry of the integrand about $x=0$. This in some ways agrees with the intuitive idea of thinking about the "signed area under the curve" - since the enclosed area on the left is "the same" as the enclosed area on the right, with the opposite sign, the integral should vanish!

We call the value of the above limit (when it exists) the *Cauchy principal value* of the integral. It isn't really the value of the integral (at least with the usual Riemann integral definition), but it allows us to prescribe in an intuitive way what the value "should be".

So what is the answer? Formally, the integral doesn't exist by the definition of Riemann integrability. But we can still ascribe to the integral a value that at least makes sense in some way via the Cauchy principal value. Keep in mind that this is not *really* the value of the integral, but it agrees with intuition.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is divergent this is because
$$ \int_{-2}^{2} \frac{(x^2+4)}{x} dx=\int_{-2}^2xdx+4\int_{-2}^2\frac1xdx $$
and the second integral has the primitive $\ln|x|$ which is undefined at $x=0$.
However, the principle value of the integral is $0$. In fact,
$$ P.V.\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{(x^2+4)}{x} dx=\lim_{\epsilon^+\to0}\bigg(\int_{-2}^{-\epsilon} \frac{(x^2+4)}{x} dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{2} \frac{(x^2+4)}{x} dx\bigg)=0.$$